# NPN base resistor common collector

Tags: transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4c2eI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi, usual apologies here, total enthusiastic amateur noob, etc.

The situation is: a Common Collector NPN transistor.

Question: Is it okay to omit the resistor R2?  (that is, R2 = 0 Ohms)?

The way I understand it, when the switch is closed, the voltage at the Emitter (as indicated) would be 5V – 0.7V = 4.3V. The reason for that is that both the Collector and the Base are connected directly to 5V, and that VBE must be 0.7 V for silicon-based transistors. Therefore the voltage drop from the Collector to the Emitter will 0.7 V rather than the normal 0.05 to 0.10 V.

But if that is the case, if I want to calculate the value of R2, the total voltage drop is the same, irrespective of whether I calculate it through the loop containing the switch, or going through the transistor form the Collector to the Emitter. Therefore IR = 0 for the Base resistor so that R2 must be 0 Ohms.

Elsewhere I came across the injunction: “Do NOT omit the Base Resistor!” so now I’m uncertain.

(I’m really trying to design a circuit to drive an PWM input to an H-bridge from an Intel Edison, so the above is not my complete circuit – it just crystallises one of the many current conceptual difficulties I have. This particular part has to do with an AND gate, so there will at least be another transistor and a pull-down resistor, and so on.)

Comment: You can find your answer here (from a similar question):
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/134064/103420

Comment: You're welcome. But you'd be quicker if you made a search ;)

Comment: I did, I did. But I am not yet at the stage where I know what to search for. "Do I need a base resistor" is still a bit generic for me.

Comment: @RohatKılıç that is for linear load R's in series....

Comment: @pipe  not same load

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Sure, but still the same question. As you can see, it even solved his problem.

Comment: not the same question as base R affects emitter output Z which affects degeneration which affects MOSFET ringing.. this suggest may cause a problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can drive it direct in most DC cases, but without a small Series R Emitter followers can become oscillatory with capacitive loads and step pulses.

The value needs to degenerate positive feedback and can be as small as the output impedance, but usually more.  Series R's are often placed between bridge drivers to MOSFET Gates to tradeoff between instability and slew rate.

I don't have a short answer, but I references.
The Rs loop including (Rb/hFE + Re ) must have a Q<1 thus total gain <1 with positive feedback with ESL and ESR of load, otherwise you have an emitter Follower "Hartley Oscillator". When you add a series R, you reduce the Q of parasitic ESL and load Ciss, it is ok to reduce Rb to 0.

- http://audioworkshop.org/downloads/AMPLIFIERS_OSCILLATION_BJT_CIRCUITS.pdf

https://www.google.ca/search?q=emitter+follower+oscillation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Uu4AWIbQEcrcjwT79JLQDA

Comment: I’ve built 2 rudimentary circuits in my entire life (as in the past week), so I’m still trying to do everything with NPN transistors – I’ve not progressed to PNP transistors yet.
But picking up from a reply mentioned by Rohat Kılıç above, it occurs to me that maybe I should do this with PNP transistors instead: I won’t get the voltage drop, and I would HAVE to use base resistors anyway,  so maybe that would address the oscillating issues you mention as well? Would that be a better design?

Comment: insufficient details on layout and components.  best to follow expert designs that work , if you can find.