# Building a linear current regulator from a 12V 50A SMPS using a BJT array and a DAC

Tags: bjt, current-source, dac, constant-current

I have an application where I need a digitally controlled constant current power supply capable of currents up to 50A. I have made a digitally controlled constant current power supply in the past, but only up to 200mA, and I imagine I will need very different design constraints for this one.

I have skimmed the service manuals for high current power supplies such as the HP 6259 which seem to use an array of BJTs for regulating current but I am not sure of how to re-implement this design.

I am planning to use [this 12V, 50A SMPS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FPB8WHJ) as a 12V source capable of supplying up to 50A. I have drafted up a circuit using the [HP 6259 service manual,](https://userequip.com/files/specs/6155/Manual%20(3).pdf) , this [Stackexchange post on BJT-controlled constant current source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383373/bjt-constant-current-resistor-equations), and [this post on running BJTs in parallel](https://forum.digikey.com/t/bipolar-transistors-connected-in-parallel/535):

[image]

But I am not sure if this is correct, and even if it is, I am not sure how to calculate the relationship between DAC output and current through the load. I am also not sure how to select the specific BJT model to use or how to select the values of resistance for the balancing resistors.

If anyone could provide any advice that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What bandwidth and SNR is needed? Do you care about massive heatsinks, water cooling?

Comment: That's not how it was done by HP 50 yrs ago, need better load specs and ripple

Comment: Good grief that’s walking over the bridge to get to water. Get yourself a programmable CC/CV supply if it’s a one-off or build an adjustable CC/CV control loop for your existing power supply?

Comment: If you wish to build it yourself from non-expensive PSU, may be it is easier, faster and effective to add a DAC to feedback path of that SMPS (roughly)?

Comment: I would like stability to about 0.01A if possible but even 0.1A should be fine. I don't mind heatsinking and cooling everything. An adjustable CV power supply capable of supplying up to 50A seems to cost about $1000 and I cannot find any CC power supply with these specs for less than $2000.

Comment: What will this 'constant current' power supply be powering?

Comment: It will be powering a heating element of sorts for a materials science experiment.

Comment: As Vladimir suggested, modify the power supply so you can vary the voltage or use pwm to modulate the power but this might cause problems with induction or build a buck converter with variable voltage.

Comment: Another simple solution is to modify your heaters for using AC grid voltage directly and use period-skip technique for regulation. Your temperature control system should be closed-loop, so great stability of power source is not required. Additional information is required to give you better advices.